# Find expected value of red and blue ball pairs

Tags: probability, expected-value

The problem is the following. Let's say we have two boxes, each with $R$ red balls and $B$ blue balls, i.e $R+B$ balls in each of them. We draw pairs of balls, choosing one from each of the boxes until there are no more balls left. Given $X$ the total number of red and blue balls pairs drawn, I am trying to find $E(X)$.

I considered this approach. We start by defining new variables $X_1,...,X_{R+B}$ where $X_i = 1$ if the pair of balls drawn in the ith extraction is blue and red (regardless of their order) and $0$ if it isn't. Now by linearity of expectation we have that:
$$E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{R+B} E(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{R+B}P(X_i = 1)$$

Now $P(X_1 = 1) = \frac{2RB}{(R+B)^2}$. My problem is that finding $P(X_i = 1)$ for $i > 1$ seems to be much harder since I think that I would have to condition the probability over all the possible previous extractions. I was wondering whether that is the best approach or there is an easier way to find $E(X)$.

Comment: I think it's simpler than that.  Without loss of generality, you can assume (by permuting pairs as needed) that the first $R$ balls drawn from the first box are all red.  Under that assumption, calculate the expected value of the number of blue balls drawn from the second box among the first $R$ draws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity suffices.  The beauty of linearity is that it holds even if, as here, the variables are dependent.

Any given pair has probability $\frac {2RB}{(R+B)^2}$ as you remark, so the answer is simply $$E[X]=(R+B)\times \frac {2RB}{(R+B)^2}=\frac {2RB}{(R+B)}$$

As a quick sanity check, suppose $(R,B)=(1,1)$.  Then, if the first pair is mixed (a $\frac 12$ chance), the second is also.  And if the first is single colored, so is the second.  Thus you have two mixed pairs or none with equal chances, so the expected number is $1$, as the formula implies.

Comment: Great! What is the intuition behind the fact that any pair has the same probability? I guess I could prove it by induction, but the arithmetic involved would be kind of demanding.

Comment: Suppose the balls were numbered (to make them all distinguishable).  Then any ball has an equal chance to be chosen in any position.  It follows that the probability that the $k^{th}$ draw from Box $i$ is Red is $\frac R{R+B}$ and so on.

Comment: Note: the inductive argument is no harder (just less intuitive).  Suppose you have proven it for all $R+B<n$.  We now want to prove it for $R+B=n$.  But draw the first ball. We see that the probability that the $k^{th}$ draw is Red is $\frac R{R+B}\times \frac {R-1}{R+B-1}+\frac B{R+B}\times \frac {R}{R+B-1}=\frac R{R+B}$.